# Does C* check the OS cached data if Row Cache is disabled

Tags: caching, cassandra

Just saw the [Read Path](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts/read-path-cassandra-read-path) explanation from DataStax. They say that the Row Cache is turned off by default because it's a waste since the OS already caches that data. But one thing that's not clear to me is if C* actually checks that cached data in case the Row Cache is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But one thing that's not clear to me is if C* actually checks that cached data in case the Row Cache is off?

By **OS Cache** the doc means [system pagecache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). It works transparently for the application so Cassandra does not need to check anything.

From Cassandra point of view, accessing a flat file on disk or the same flat file put in page cache is the same.

Of course, for performance reasons, it is possible to **ask** the OS to put the file you're accessing in the page cache. Read this [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) Java doc

Comment: Thanks! Given this, I don't see any reason why we would want to use Row Cache if we already have the data (if it was loaded before) on the page cache. Is it because there's a chance that the data is removed from the page cache regularly but not from the Row Cache?